# Convert socket response to dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting response from socket as below:

```
(
    {
    response =   {
        demo =   (           
                            {
                "code" = 612064;
                "code1" = "T";
                "code2" = "http://www.XXXXXXX.com";
            }        
        );
        response = "get_nearby";

    };
    status = success;
    }
)
```

How to convert to dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you are showing is not `Dictionary` it is Array of `Dictionary`, So try to convert your response to `[[String:AnyObject]]`.

```
if let array = yourResponse as? [[String:AnyObject]], let firstDic = array.first {
    print(firstDic)
    print(firstDic["status"])
}
```

Comment: I'm getting response as ["response": {
demo = (   {
                "code" = 612064;
                "code1" = "T";
                "code2" = "http://www.XXXXXXX.com";
            }        );  response = "get_nearby";

    };
    status = success;
    } ]

Comment: how to convert this to dictionary?

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas It is output of the `print(firstDic)` right?

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas You haven't replied? Is it working now?

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas If my answer helps you please accept it show it helps others too :)